# How to separate parts of NSString?

Tags: iphone

I have a NSMutableArray of NSStrings where each element of array has the format equal to @"key is 1::value is 1". Now I want to store string part coming before "::" in an array1 and string part coming after "::" in an array2. How can I do that?

Comment: can you post some code my friend please???

Answer (score 0):

The key to splitting your strings is to use the [componentsSeparatedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) method on NSString to separate your string into an NSArray. Read the docs on how this method acts with blank strings etc, but it's what you'd use.

You said you have an array of strings, so the basic implementation would involve iterating over that array and adding each element to the two other arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *string in arrayOfStrings)
{
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"];
    if ([components count] == 2)
    {
        NSString *obj1 = [components objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *obj2 = [components objectAtIndex:1];
        [array1 addObject:obj1];
        [array2 addObject:obj2];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's only one bit of the answer the o.p. is looking for.  S/he also wants you to tell how to separate the items into separate arrays... and while we're on the subject, what happens if there is no value (e.g. empty string or NULL) after a key?  Hmm?

Comment: The strings won't be nil or NULL if they're already in an  NSArray and the code has been updated to demonstrate a for loop. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Code :**

```
NSArray *temp = [YourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"];
NSString *str1 = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *str2 = [temp objectAtIndex:1];
```

But prior to accessing the Objects in the Array .. check for whether it contains the value.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
[array1 addObject:[[YourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"] objectAtIndex:0]];
[array2 addObject:[[YourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
NSString *s = @"key is 1::value is 1";

NSArray *a = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"];

NSLog(@" -> %@ --> %@", [a objectAtIndex:0], [a objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. I will keep adding the beforeString and afterString in array1 and array 2 respectively while iterating the elements of original array

```
for(int i=0;i<self.originalArray.count;i++)
    {
      NSString *temp=[self.originalArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSRange r = [temp rangeOfString:@"::"];
        NSString *beforeString = [temp substringToIndex:r.location];
        NSString *afterString = [temp substringFromIndex:r.location+2];

        [array1 addObject:beforeString];  
        [array2 addObject:afterString];  
     }
```